# How to extract null values from Bigquery table as a TableRow object

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to extract data from a BigQuery table using Google Cloud Dataflow.

My BigQuery table has few empty values(for `String` datatype) and null (for `Numeric` data types).
When I try to extract the data in dataflow using `BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery(select * from table_name)`, I don't see the columns with null values.

How can I achieve this to get all the columns as part of the TableRow object?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the current behavior BigQueryIO connector. Null values are ignored in the resulting element. But empty string values should be available. Can you just assume values that are not available in the resulting element to be null ?